# Can the laptop hardware corrupt the HDD/SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, freeze, filesystem-corruption

long version:

Around 4-5 months ago, I replaced the HDD in my Asus x501a laptop with a SSD (ADATA Ultimate SU650 120GB SATA3), as it would freeze occasionally and the HDD made a nasty scratchy noise. After the replacement the freezes were gone and my laptop worked just fine.

However, after 4-5 months the freezing came back, but it was minor, there were no full on freezes like there were with the HDD. Occasionally, when booting Linux (Deepin 15) it would say that I had corrupted blocks and had to manually run fsck. Today, the laptop completely froze and I had to force shutdown it (waited for 10 min to unfreeze). After powering it back on, I was greeted with a black screen and got kicked into BIOS after a while. In the BIOS boot menu, I noticed that I had not boot devices. After googling, everything pointed that the SSD got corrupted and needed to be replaced.

I kinda find it hard to believe that the SSD would break so fast, sure it was a cheap one, but I couldn't find anything against ADATA's poor quality on the internet. Maybe I just got really unlucky and got a faulty model.

I really don't want to buy a new laptop, but I also don't want to buy a new SSD, knowing that somehow the laptops hardware may corrupt it again a few months later. Especially that the symptoms that I got were almost identical to the HDD.

In terms of usage, I used the laptop for NodeJS programming and running SQL databases, nothing too serious. One thing also, around 1-2GB of RAM would be constantly swapped (as sometimes 4 GB were not enough), could that also have an effect?

short version:

SSD got corrupted after 4-5 months of usage, could the laptop hardware be at fault? Or is it most likely just a faulty SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's coincidence that both your drives failed so close together in time.

The ADATA Ultimate SU650 120 has very poor reviews. Many people report the drive fails within a few months  of purchasing it, according to Amazon and Newegg reviews. These kind of reviews are fairly common in low end, cheap SSDs. I would stay away from them, and stick to quality name brands.

Comment: Mhm, thank you for the reply, i guess I'll go with Samsung this time